# Прочитать с середины файл без чтения его начала на Rust'е

Tags: файлы, потоки-данных, filestream, rust, fstream

```
let f = File::open("file").unwrap();
let reader = BufReader::new(f).seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(2));
for b in reader.iter().next() {
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Выводит то, что находится внутри io::SeekFrom::Start, т.е. 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какой-то странный цикл у вас. По идее должно быть как-то так:

```
let f = File::open("file").unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);
reader.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(2)).unwrap();
for b in reader.bytes() {
  println!("{}", b);
}
```

Метод `seek()` возвращает `Result<u64>`, то есть новую позицию в файле.
Он вызывается на `&mut self`, значит reader должен быть `mut`, иначе не заработает.

Что делает ваш код: вы открываете файл и смещаете указатель на 2 байта, сохраняя `Result<u64>` в `reader`. Потом вы преобразовываете `Result` в итератор с помощью `iter()` и вызываете на итераторе `next()`, получаете `Option<u64>`, равный `Some(2)`. А потом по опции итерируете (`Option<_>` реализует `IntoIterator`, так что этому типу можно итерировать). Итератор весело выдаёт один элемент — 2.

Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок в будущем, внимательно читайте документацию на используемые трейты и типы: ни в трейте [Read](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html), ни в типе [BufReader](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) нет метода `iter()`, однако в `Read` есть метод `bytes()`, который вам был нужен. А вот метод [Seek::seek](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) возвращает `Result<u64>`. Кроме того стоит больше прочитать про интерфейс [итераторов](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/index.html), так как вы, судя по всему, до конца не поняли эту идею, раз вызываете на итераторе метод `next()` явно.

Comment: 1. `for b in BufReader::new(f).bytes() {
  println!("{}", b);
}` повлияет ли на бинарник формирование такого цикла по сравнению с прежним вариантом - использование переменной `reader`?
2. адаптер `map` оптимально ли использовать для какого-нибудь `println!`?

Comment: 1. не думаю, что сильно повлияет, по любому будут созданы структуры `File` и `BufReader`. Возможно оптимизатор какие-нибудь вызовы лучше заинлайнит разве что, но вряд ли. 2. нет, лучше map для такого не юзать, он немного для другого придуман, хотя, конечно можно, но оптимизатор с замыканиями не всегда хорошо справляется пока что. Кроме того map возвращает ленивый итератор, так что чтобы запустить сам процесс, придётся вызвать что-то типа `.count()` или `.fold()` потом.

Comment: Если очень-очень хочется функциональный стиль и монады, то можно сделать как-то так:

    `File::open("file").map(BufReader::new).and_then(|mut file| { file.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(2)); file }).map(|file| file.bytes()).and_then(|mut bytes| bytes.map(|b| println!("{}", b)).count()));`

Но это не эффективно и громоздко.